# zepto.js page animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, zepto

Does anyone know how to change the type of animation the page/sections uses? I read the docs but couldn't understand a single thing. I like the framework and I really want to give it a try but there is absolutely NO tutorials or documentation for that matter.

Answer (score 6):

You can use those Zepto animations, which are native webkit transitions:

`$('.pages').anim({ translateX: window.innerWidth + 'px'}, 0.5, 'ease-out');`

or

`$('.pages').anim({ translate3d: window.innerWidth + 'px, 0, 0'}, 0.5, 'ease-out');`

List of animation available:

```
var supportedTransforms = [
        'scale', 'scaleX', 'scaleY',
        'translate', 'translateX', 'translateY', 'translate3d',
        'skew',      'skewX',      'skewY',
        'rotate',    'rotateX',    'rotateY',    'rotateZ',    'rotate3d',
        'matrix'
      ];
```